# Same flutter_bloc for two sceens

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

This is the use case, I have invoice list and each invoice have list of item , flutter_bloc:6.0.0 is used

[image: Invoice Screen]

[image: Item Screen]

[image: Error page]

When navigating to Invoice to Details , error will occured

This is State Classes/ Bloc

[image: Code segments]

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the bloc, is that in some situation you are not returning a widget.

Comment: Example, yout have:
if a=1 return widget
else if a=2 return widget
else if a=3 return widget

So, if you get a = 4 you will get a erro because you are not returning a widget, you dont have a else or a return widget after ifs block

Comment: your are correct , I was able to figure out the issue, Want to detect the second screen back button event and pull to data again currently it is empty when come back